# Optimize a regex for German mobile numbers

Tags: python, regex, match

I have a Regex which extracts German mobile phone numbers from a website:

```
[^\d]((\+49|0049|0)1[567]\d{1,2}([ \-/]*\d){7})(?!\d)
```

As you can see in the [demo](https://regex101.com/r/jZxzfM/1) it works quite well. The only pattern which doesn't match yet is:

```
+49 915175461907
```

Please see more examples in the linked demo. The problem is the whitespace behind `+49`.

How do I need to change the current regex pattern in order to match even these kind of patterns?

Comment: A single optional space can be matched with space plus question mark.

Comment: Instead of the `[^\d]` your have at the start, use a negative look-behind: `(?<!\d)`. This way it will also match directly at the beginning of the string. Your current regex fails for this case.

Comment: Not correct dupe because problem is not just about allowing spaces. Negated character class `[^\d]` will cause it to not match if input starts with `+4915207829969`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add an optional white space:

```
[^\d]((\+49|0049|0)\s?(1|9)[1567]\d{1,2}([ \-/]*\d){7,8})(?!\d)
```

**Update-Capturing beginning of line**

If you want is to match numbers without them necessarily starting with a line break you can use this. It matches anything except digits before phone number:

```
 (^|[^\d])((\+49|0049|0)\s?(1|9)[1567]\d{1,2}([ \-/]*\d){7,8})(?!\d)
```

[test it here](https://regex101.com/r/hCs1It/1)

Answer (score 5):

A better regex would be:

```sh
(?<!\d)(?:\+49|0049|0) *[19][1567]\d{1,2}(?:[ /-]*\d){7,8}(?!\d)
```

[Updated RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/jZxzfM/3)

**Changes:**

- `(?<!\d)`: Make sure previous character is not a digit
- `[19][1567]`: Match `1` or `9` followed by one of the `[1567]` digit
- `{7,8}`: Match 7 or 8 repetitions of given construct
- Better to keep an unescaped hyphen at first or last position in a character class
- Avoid capturing text that you don't need by using non-capture group

Answer (score 3):

No brain method : removing space before regex.

Otherwise matching non withe space in regex is \s so (maybe too much parenthesis)

```
[^\d](((\+49|0049|0)([\s]{0,1})1)[567]\d{1,2}([ \-/]*\d){7})(?!\d)
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. Works great except for the numbers which start have a ``9`` like this one: ``+49 915175461907``